# Basic Authentication Java SOAP WebService Client

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

java artifacts for Soap Web Service Client using wsimport from a WSDL. Which produced:

AppPortalSMupdate.java with some sample code from it
public interface AppPortalSMupdate {

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "RetrieveAppPortalSMupdate", action = "Retrieve")
@WebResult(name = "RetrieveAppPortalSMupdateResponse", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7", partName = "RetrieveAppPortalSMupdateResponse")
public RetrieveAppPortalSMupdateResponse retrieveAppPortalSMupdate(
    @WebParam(name = "RetrieveAppPortalSMupdateRequest", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7", partName = "RetrieveAppPortalSMupdateRequest")
    RetrieveAppPortalSMupdateRequest retrieveAppPortalSMupdateRequest);
```

AppPortalSMupdate_Service.java

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "AppPortalSMupdate", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7", wsdlLocation ="http://ss_user:sqzblsft@msmapptst001.lvh.com:13088/SM/7/AppPortalSMupdate.wsdl")
```

public class AppPortalSMupdate_Service  extends Service{

```
private final static URL APPPORTALSMUPDATE_WSDL_LOCATION;
private final static WebServiceException APPPORTALSMUPDATE_EXCEPTION;
private final static QName APPPORTALSMUPDATE_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7", "AppPortalSMupdate");

static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://ss_user:sqzblsft@msmapptst001.lvh.com:13088/SM/7/AppPortalSMupdate.wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
    APPPORTALSMUPDATE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    APPPORTALSMUPDATE_EXCEPTION = e;
```

This is the call to in my main from test client class:

AppPortalSMupdate appUpdate = calc.getAppPortalSMupdate();

UpdateAppPortalSMupdateResponse appResponse = appUpdate.updateAppPortalSMupdate(requestMessage);

My question is the web service needs a user id and password. How do I add a user id and password in my call in the main. This is being used inside a liferay portlet.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Could you please fix the formatting of your code? It is really hard to read.

Comment: hey mafor how do I go about doing that? thanks

Comment: Could you add to your question what is the authentication scheme of your call ? Is it HTTP Basic (as the title seems to imply), is it by WS-Security ? You need to know how the authentication is expected before getting a usefull answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `@HandlerChain` annotation and configure them by implementing the `SOAPHandler` interface. 
Let me know if you need more clarification.